# What devices are supported by the connected devices framework?

Tags: interoperability

One of the new features in v10 is [support for connected devices](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/connected-device-framework/).

How can I find out if a particular device is supported by Mathematica?  Is there a complete list?  Is support being added continually?

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/UsingConnectedDevices.html) says:

> Many classes of devices listed in the [Wolfram Connected Devices Project](http://devices.wolfram.com/) are immediately supported within the Wolfram Language.

Out of curiosity, I connected a Garmin nüvi50 and ran [`FindDevices`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindDevices.html) to see if it would recognize it and be able to import tracks.  I got the result:

```
{DeviceObject[{"Camera", 1}], DeviceObject[{"FunctionDemo", 1}], 
 DeviceObject[{"RandomSignalDemo", 1}], DeviceObject[{"WriteDemo", 1}]}
```

The only device it recognized here was the built-in camera.  Is `FindDevices` generally sufficient to find out of a device is supported, or is manual configuration necessary for some devices?

Comment: A related question would be how to implement support for custom devices.  But that probably deserves its own separate post.

Answer (score 2):

Surely this is only a partial response. The (somewhat) supported devices up to now you can find [here](http://devices.wolfram.com/measured-quantities.html):

[image]

Some of them are allready listed within Wolfram Language & Dokumentation Center ([link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/device/TinkerForgeWeatherStation.html)):

[image]

Just a guess, but devices with the note "Wolfram Language Device Connection" seem to have a "functionality":

[image]

"Developing Device Drivers" is still under "Draft" ([link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingDeviceDrivers.html#647897357)).

Whether and how the "Connected Devices Project" will interact or benefit from the API/NET/Link/Framework Stuff(?) is a very exciting question ([link](http://www.tinkerforge.com/en/doc/Software/API_Bindings_Mathematica.html)).